# Transactions not Persisting In Time in Jetty

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt, jpa, guice

I inherited some code which, when trying to add some features, isn't working for me properly. I'm no expert at Java web, so I apologize in advance if I need any extra hand-holding to get you the information you need.

I'm developing a GWT application which is using Hibernate and Guice-Persist on the back-end to persist to MySQL. Unfortunately, I'm hitting a weird problem in which -- on one server -- a `put` transaction is not persisting to the database in time to be recognized by a subsequent `get` transaction. **Everything works perfectly in whatever version of Jetty is embedded with the GWT Eclipse plugin (possibly 6.1.11?) in Windows and in Tomcat6 in Linux, but when I try to run it in Linux using `jetty-maven-plugin` version `8.1.0` (also in `8.1.5`, the only two version I've tried), I get this problem with the transaction not completing in time.** (Alternatively, I'd be thrilled with a solution that just allows me to properly run my integration tests in Maven using something other than Jetty to sidestep this problem all-together. It certainly seems that the code works in every other server context I've tried).

Here's the code I'm using to persist an object:

```
public T put(T entity) {
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManager();
    EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();        
    transaction.begin();
    try {
        entity = entityManager.merge(entity);
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        transaction.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //do exception handling, including rollback
    }


    return entity;
}
```

And the get code:

```
public List<T> getAll() {
    Query query = entityManager().createQuery("select c from " + clazz.getSimpleName() + " c");

    return (List<T>) query.getResultList();
}
```

Again, what's happening is that I make an (indirect) call to `getAll()` to allow the client to see the data. Then if they make a selection, make a `put` call from the client. Then once I get the response, make a call to `getAll()` to update the data displayed to the user. Unfortunately, the data I'm getting back from the database doesn't reflect the updated data, but instead the data as it existed before the `put()` call. The database does eventually update, and when I check the database myself, it seems to be updated instantly. The web application, too, will eventually update to show the proper data if I reload the data a few times. So I'm suspect of some caching layer which may be responding to my `getAll()` request without actually checking the database, but am really not sure how to proceed -- Transactions and EntityManagers are fairly new to me.

I've tried `flush()`ing and `close()`ing my Entity Manager instead of committing my transaction and haven't had any change in behavior.

I'm injecting my EntityManager Provider in the constructor:

```
private final Class<T> clazz;
private final Provider<EntityManager> entityManagerProvider;

public BaseDao(final Class<T> clazz, final Provider<EntityManager> entityManagerProvider) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
    this.entityManagerProvider = entityManagerProvider;
}
```

and getting an entity manager like so:

```
protected EntityManager entityManager() {
    return entityManagerProvider.get();
}
```

Thanks!

For posterity's sake, here's my GuiceServletContextListener:

```
public class GuiceServletConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener {
@Override
protected Injector getInjector() {
    DispatchServletModule dispatchServletModule = new DispatchServletModule();
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new ServerModule(), new JpaPersistModule(getPersistenceUnit()),
            dispatchServletModule);

    PersistService persistService = injector.getInstance(PersistService.class);
    persistService.start();

    BootStrapper bootStrapper = injector.getInstance(BootStrapper.class);
    bootStrapper.init();



    return injector;
}

private String getPersistenceUnit() {
    InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/database.properties");

    if (inputStream == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    try {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(inputStream);

        return properties.getProperty("persistenceUnit");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}


}
```

And my ServletModule:

```
public class DispatchServletModule extends ServletModule {      
  @Override
  public void configureServlets() {
    serve("/" + ActionImpl.DEFAULT_SERVICE_NAME + "*").with(DispatchServiceImpl.class);
  }
}
```

I've tried adding a filter in configureServlets() instead of starting the persistence session manually in an attempt to use session-per-http-request (per [this page](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/JPA)) with no luck.

Comment: Well, you should start with giving us ANY information at all...

Comment: Agreed... Pressed enter too soon while entering tags. My bad. Give me one moment...

Comment: Just of curiosity: what is the debugging output tell you? Usually you should see the SQLs executed. Are you **sure** it is not throwing an Exception that you just catch and silently ignore?

Comment: I don't have Hibernate's SQL output enabled. I can give that a try to make sure everything's being executed in the proper order. Also, I'm hesitant to think there's any error on the `put()`, seeing as the database *is* eventually consistent. So everything's working properly, just not in the right order (in one environment).

Comment: One curious entry: `2012-08-23 13:07:04.510:INFO:oejpw.PlusConfiguration:No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.` I don't notice this on my other server logs (though I might be missing it).

Comment: Are you sure that the GET actually occurs after the PUT? Do you know if Hibernate is doing something like `INSERT DELAYED` or anything like that?

Comment: The hibernate log indeed reflects a PUT before the GET. Could an `INSERT DELAYED` make that order appear inaccurate?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should probably be rolling back the transaction in your `catch` block and not ignoring the exception (at least log it).  But `guice-persist` supports the `@Transactional` annotation, so really you shouldn't need to do manual transaction management at all.  See [Transactions - google-guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Transactions).

Comment: Thanks. Hidden in the "do exception handling" is actually a `rollback()` call. I'll investigate that link you mention.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your comments... are you suggesting that the `@Transactional` annotation will change the behavior of the code and my fix the issue? Or just be easier to maintain? Would the introduction of the UnitOfWork system be helpful in ensuring that my data gets written back in time?

Comment: @Jeff: I'm not sure it will fix your problem, but it's always easier to do things the right way when you let the library do it for you.  Note though that `@Transactional` needs to be on a method of a class that is injected by Guice.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked to close the session associated with the transaction?

```
public T put(T entity) {
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManager();
    EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();        
    transaction.begin();
    try {
        entity = entityManager.merge(entity);
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        transaction.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //do exception handling, including rollback
    } finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }

    return entity;
}
```

But you can force the transaction to sync with a flush:

```
public T put(T entity) {
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManager();
    EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();        
    transaction.begin();
    try {
        entity = entityManager.merge(entity);
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        entityManager.flush();
        transaction.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //do exception handling, including rollback
    }

    return entity;
}
```

Regards,

Comment: No luck yet, but I think we might be headed in the right direction... I got an error of `EntityManager is closed` on one of my `put()` calls -- it looks like my `Provider<EntityManager>` is returning used instances of EntityManagers rather than throwing them away and making new ones. Is there a different way I should be creating my EntityManagers?

Comment: It can be useful to the following link: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html_single/

Comment: Can you be more specific with that link? I didn't see anything of immediate use to the problem. After finding that the `EntityManager`s were recycled, I realized that perhaps `clear()`ing the entityManager before returning might solve some of these issues. Indeed, it's now much more stable, but I have to manually `clear()` each `EntityManager` at the end of each function. Any ideas on how to work with this?